# UIViewController subviews added in interface builder not showing up

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, subview

Ok so basically I just used the interface builder with auto layout to add some subviews and constraints to my UIViewController. My app is supposed to segue to this view when the user wants to take a photo. I laid out a few camera buttons on a black, square UIView that will serve as the camera view once I have programmed it. Since I wanted to make the camera view a square, I also had some extra space where I just made a label that says "Take a photo!" This is how the interface builder for this view controller looks:

[image: Interface builder]

And this is how the same view looks when I run the app:

[image: App view]

I'm guessing it's something simple that I'm missing that's causing this problem but I will be grateful to anyone who can help me!

Comment: Please make sure you have connected your viewcontroller from storyboard to the viewcontroller.swift.

Comment: Yes, zohaib is right. Make sure viewcontroller is properly connected by segue. Secondly, make sure your subviews constraints are in order and they are organized properly, with proper hierarchy.

Comment: Yes I made sure that it's connected properly by segue. I can also tell because the navigation bar has the title of the view controller on it. I think the constraints are most likely the cause in that case

Comment: Ok setting the height constraint actually worked and made the subviews appear but I still want the UIView to be a square on all screen sizes. Therefore setting a constant height would not work. How can I set the height to be equal to the width

Comment: add aspect ratio 1 : 1 constraint to your view. It set width and height relation as 1 : 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using autoLayout you should set all needed constraint to the view. Otherwise it is an ambiguous layout problem, and the system is not knowing where to set your view

If you want the height to be the same like the width set the aspect ratio constraint to your view [image]

And be sure that the multiplier of constraint is 1

Answer (score 0):

Bring that subview to front, putting all other views to its back 
try it will work

parentView.bringSubview(toFront: childView)

This method can also be used to bring any subview to the front, even if you're not sure where it is:

childView.superview.bringSubview(toFront: childView)